# Text overlays itself on small screen on the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got this issue with the text overlaying itself on very small screensizes, such as mobile devices or very small windows in chrome.

[Text Logo with the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OehEz.png)

[image]

My css for the navbar looks like this:

```
.navbar-default  {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  background-image: none;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;

}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-left: 25%;
    display: block;
    border-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I'm not sure whats causing it since it never happens on my screen ("24 and iphone 6s +) since my screens are larger than some others. I got the issue as feedback from someone else who tried to check my site. It would be great if the second word just appeared below the first one in such cases.

Regards,
stAMy

Comment: adjust your line-height and/or font-size for small screens.

Comment: Could you please share the link of the page which has this issue?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar the page is mollarencafe.com

Comment: You are using `line-height: 20px` to vertically center the logo. That is too low a number for the `font-size` when the text is on 2 lines. Increase the `line-height` on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may work fine.

```
  @media(max-width: 767px){
    .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 2em;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
```

[image]

**Explanation**

You have used `margin-left: 25%;`, it occupies 25% of empty space, then the font size as `3em`. There may not have any space so the text breaks and comes in second line.

Try to use the font size and margin in media query, which I have given.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the issue! Since I'm not lvl 15 i cant give u vote up, but i've marked it as solution. Do you think the margin 25 % is a bad thing? The problem is that the logo wont stay close to the li elements if not in bigger resolution

Comment: I can't understand the meaning of "The problem is that the logo wont stay close to the li elements if not in bigger resolution". The issue in your code is the text element which has not had enough space while you applied margin as 25%. That's why it brakes to the second line.

Comment: I ment that is 25 % margin-left bad to use in general? I used it to get the logo closer to Home, meny etc.

Comment: Yep, It is not advisable to apply margin in %.

Comment: Any recommendations? px instead?